# Galaxy Tab S 10.5 Screwed

Tags: samsung

Please help guys, I was trying to flash a rom, I deleted OS, All I get is Samsung Logo, I cant get into download mode(hard key combo dont wotk) I have no recovery on, and my PC wont recognise tablet, I have already tried a few things.  Any help to recover this would be really really appreciated.

Regards

Steve

Comment: I really hate to be the one to say this, but its the end of the line for this tablet. Double check everything. If not works, either burn an effigy, or get a new one.

Comment: Key combo should work! Volume down + Power